# How to make a Machine Learning model create something new

Tags: python, machine-learning

Sorry for the terrible title, couldn't think of how to properly word it.

Basically, I have a small classification ML starter project in python using scikit learn & doc2vec which tries to differentiate satirical news headlines from real ones. That's all working and done, but I wanted to see what would happen if I then, using the trained model, had it try to generate a new satirical/real headline. I feel like this is a completely different type of problem, and I don't know where to start.

Basically my question is, how do people use ML to achieve the following:

1. Given lots of song lyrics => create song lyrics
2. Given lots of poems => write a poem

etc...

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at GANs. Having said that your post is off-topic for Stackoverflow. check the other Stackexchange pages

Comment: okay, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using LSTMs (Long Short Term Memory Models), you can decompose your corpus (the headlines) like this : 
I'll be using my first sentence as an exemple.

- input             |Label
- I                 |would
- I would           |recommend
- I would recommend |using
  .
  .

recurrent neural networks have proven effective in Language modeling.
For tokeninzing the corpus you can use Python's library Keras.